# How to implement swipe view on fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, fragmentpageradapter, swipeview

I'm trying to implement a swipe inside a fragment! My application use a Navigation Drawer Layout and I change view with the drawer. All the view that I show are fragment. Now, I want to implement into a specific fragment an horizontal swipe. How can I do this thing? my code is here :

```
public class MybookingFragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View Rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybooking, parent, false);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) Rootview.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SlidingPagerAdapter(fragmentManager));
    return Rootview;
}
```

my adapter code is here

```
public class SlidingPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
public SlidingPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragmentClass = UpcomingOrder.class;
        case 1:
            fragmentClass = RunningOrder.class;
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentClass = CompletedOrder.class;
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = UpcomingOrder.class;
            break;
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // For this contrived example, we have a 100-object collection.
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}
```

}

Comment: I think you can try ViewPager or if you try some other way post your code here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this below example. I think you are asking this only

[Example 1](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/)

[Example 2](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

[Tabs swipe](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

You have to use main fragment. with in that fragment you have to load all sub-fragments(tabs).